# SocketTimeoutException emerges when insert millions of records to hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have build a hbase cluster consists of nine nodes.Every node has 64GB memory capacity.Now I want to insert millions of records to hbase.In order to improve the write performace ,I create 20 threads in every node,and also set writebuffer to 64MB in every node and auto flush is false.

After data prepared and configuration setted, I start the hbase cluster.
   But when the records reach to a certain degree， a problem emerges.

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 2000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for read. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/10.168.56.192:47017 remote=node4/10.168.56.190:60020] on node4,60020,1406724569748, tracking started Wed Jul 30 21:12:05 CST 2014, retrying after 10019 ms, replay 91232 ops.

what can I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is maybe your timeout value ... try to increase it (hbase.rpc.timeout) in your hbase-site.xml file.

Comment: I have set hbase.rpc.timeout=60000,but it doesn't work.

Comment: And what is your zookeeper.session.timeout  value ?